# Where to put partial templates for multiple models rendered into a single view?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a parent model, let's call it `Folder`, to which several children models link. All children are subclasses of a base class `File`. Let's call the children `M_File(File)` `N_File(File)`, etc.

```py
class Folder(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(...)
  meta_data_1 = …

class File(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(...)

class M_File(File):
  custom_field_1: ...
  custom_field_n: ...

class N_File(File):
  custom_field_1: ...
  custom_field_n: ...

etc.
```

I would like to build a `FolderDetailView` which renders also all related files. To render each file, I would like to use a custom template as the files are fairly different.

This should be possible by passing all files to the FolderDetailView and looping over them in the template like so:

```
{% for file in files %}
  {% if file.filetype == 'M_File' %}
    ...Markup to render M_File...
  {% elif file.filetype == 'N_File' %}
    ...Markup to render N_File...
  etc.
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Yet looking at this, I cannot help but think that this cannot be the best or pythonic way. Is there another, more elegant way of achieving this? I've been thinking whether it's possible to build something similar to what Forms do when they render themselves once added to the page like so `{{ form }}`.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an attribute to your models to indicate their template:-

```
class Folder(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(...)
  meta_data_1 = …

class File(models.Model):
  file_template = 'template_name1.html'
  name = models.CharField(...)

class M_File(File):
  file_template = 'template_name2.html'
  custom_field_1: ...
  custom_field_n: ...

class N_File(File):
  file_template = 'template_name3.html'
  custom_field_1: ...
  custom_field_n: ...
```

And in the template:-

```
{% for file in files %}
  {% include file.file_template %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That does make sense in a way, but doesn't it violate the separation of view and model?

Comment: Now that I see yes it does, but considering your use case of having a model render itself already does that so I cannot think of a way that doesn't.